# How can I make available same setting of Gnome-tweak tool for all other users in my system?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, configuration, tweak

I'm able to configure windows 10 theme using Gnome-tweak tool for 1 user. But I need the same setup should reflect for all other user in the same system. Want to re-use the extensions, themes and icons which I have downloaded.

Early reply would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: extensions, themes and icons can be placed in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `/usr/share/themes` to use globally..

Comment: how many user you have?

Comment: 3 users in same machine

Comment: did you try the script?

Comment: These are the extensions I'm trying to use.. but not sure how to activate these for muliple user at once.. users are something like : "kamal", "lotus"    
1.Dash-to-panel
     2. Arc-menu
     3. Panel-osd
     4. User Themes

Comment: oh you want to enable those extensions for all??

Comment: are all the extensions installed as system extensions??

Comment: yes.. for 1 user its installed but as soon as I'm logging in with other user ubuntu setup comes. I want windows 10 setup should populate as I setup in other user for all available user in the same machine

Comment: is that user administrator account?

Comment: yes.. having admin privilege

Comment: 0k then its possible as work around only.. I will edit the answer.. can you post the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions`

Comment: utpal@yesuusubuntu-All-Series:/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions

(process:5447): dconf-WARNING **: 17:39:22.520: unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/local': Failed to open file “/etc/dconf/db/local”: open() failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance
['arc-menu@linxgem33.com']

Comment: the way you are expecting is possible for guest user.. but for standard users I don't have idea..

Comment: could you please tell me for guest users

Comment: enable all the extensions you need n run the command again..

Comment: yes I will share you the link for guest user setup..

Comment: yes please.. atleast that can help me a bit to get the idea

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession

Answer (score 0):

you may achieve this with a script something like below, for example to set the `clock-show-seconds` to `true`

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -Hu <user1> dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
sudo -Hu <user2> dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
sudo -Hu <user3> dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
```

and run the script..

Similarly first determine your `gsettings` keys first for extensions, themes and icons.. modify the above script and run..

change `<user1>` `<user2>` `<user3>` in the example with your real user names..